# Razor view with IQueryable and IEnumerable

Tags: indexing

I have a Razor view (ASP.NET MVC)

When I use

```
@model IEnumerable<DAL.Models.Product>
```

I can make table header by calling:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
```

But when I change `IEnumerable` to `IQueryable`, I must specify an index like this:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Name)
```

I have to indicate an index of model. Why is it?

Comment: I believe you meant to say "I **can** make table header" instead of "can't"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14392427/1366901 says:

> @html.DisplayNameFor IS special in that it has an overload for
>   IEnumerable models. It knows you're really just after the display name
>   for the property and since you have a strongly typed list it knows how
>   to find the display name. It's a convenient feature!

There are two ways to get around it - either call ToList() on the IQueryable to make it into an IEnumerable in your controller:

```
// in your controller, change the return statement to
return resultsQuery.ToList();
```

or, instead of specifying an index, you can use FirstOrDefault(), which will still work if your IQueryable has zero elements:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Name)
```